# Provide support for iPv6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, docker, ipv6

We are using rails for one of our applications. There is also an iOS app which relies on the rails backend to authenticate users and other operations. Since, apple require apps to support iPv6, I was wondering what is the best way to convert my rails backend which is containerised using docker and deployed using amazon ecs, to provide support to iPv6.

For the rails part I have been able to boot up the rails backend to listen over both iPv4 and iPv6. Here is a copy of my Dockerfile used to boot up the container.

```
FROM ruby:2.4.1

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev 
nodejs cron postgresql-client-9.4 dos2unix

ENV APP_HOME /my_app
RUN  mkdir $APP_HOME
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

RUN echo 'gem: --no-rdoc --no-ri' >> "$HOME/.gemrc"

RUN gem install bundler

ADD Gemfile $APP_HOME/Gemfile
ADD Gemfile.lock $APP_HOME/Gemfile.lock


RUN bundle install

ADD . $APP_HOME

RUN find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 dos2unix
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /car/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* && 
apt-get --purge remove -y dos2unix
EXPOSE 80

# Boot the server
CMD echo env
CMD rake build


#this is how I was booting the server for only iPv4  
#CMD bundle install && rails s -b '0.0.0.0' -p 80

#booting for both iPv4 and iPv6
CMD bundle install && rails s -b [::] -p 80
```

So far i've had a look at these links:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html

https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/tutorials/networkingcontainers/

https://blog.cloudflare.com/supporting-the-transition-to-ipv6-only-networking-services-for-ios/

But nothing too concrete, and I am completely lost on what might be other critical steps to make all of this work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you actually had an app rejected? What was the reason?

Comment: If you are using CloudFlare, it is not clear why you would need to change anything in your backend systems... https://www.cloudflare.com/ipv6/

Comment: @Micheal yeas they were complaining about our app not supporting iPv6.

I will look into cloudfare looks interesting.